# Object detection and tracking in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Im Recently new here, we have made for our school project a cell detection. That functions under the microscope and detect the cells from PNG images that come out of our software.

On these images there will be a color detection done from tracking.js and then it returns te X and Y position of the image dimensions of the center of the cell.

Our concerning is that the cells we have under our microscope evolve so we take every minute automatically an image of this. So we have a set of 10 images with cells and also dissapearing and new cells. What would be the best way to identify them as new cells, and the cells still exist in the timeframe to identify them by an ID, and the dissapearing cells remove as object.

A lot of text, lets see what we've got right now.

Now as the detection works fine thats great. For each cell we make a new object with the following code:

```
var cells = [];

celltrack = function (x, y) {
    xoutput = (img.offsetLeft + x);
    youtput = (img.offsetTop + y);

    cells = new cell('cell');
    cells.id = count++;
    cells.x = xoutput;
    cells.y = youtput;
}

cell = function (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.id = 0;
    this.x = "x";
    this.y = "y";
}
```

A couple of main questions on this moment:

1. Is this the correct way to create the objects containing the cell info ?
2. What is the best way to identify a cell before create of delete a object ?
3. If a cell has moved, how can we link the cell to the same object with 2 different locations.

Thats it for now, if we have got further improvements in our project we keep you informed.

Comment: you declare `cells` as _array_ but assing one object

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is:

- Every minute you will get an image of cells, then properties of cells will be analyzed, the output is a series (an array) of positions for the cells in the image
- You would like to track how cells create/disappear/move between time periods

With those assumptions, I think:

1. Yes, you can use the **cell** constructor function defined in your snippet, though normally we will capitalize constructor functions (to indicate they should be used with *new* keyword, as in **Cell**). The properties that goes into the newly created object are up to you, now they are *type*, *id*, *x* and *y*.
2. I think that depends on the rules of identifying cells, based on the input we have (just positions), I am not sure we have a good solution here. Are there other properties of cells we can consider and extract in each image?
3. It relates to the last question, but once you can identify cells, you can update the cell objects between time periods, the history of locations for a cell can be kept in the Cell object itself, maybe a property called *locations* of type **Array**.

Comment: Thanks, you mean that we need another way to detect the cells on our image to identify them? Do you have options to point us in de right directio n ? What propertys could be usefull to identify them, as structure and position changes over time ?

Comment: @OliviervdSloot how to identify cells would be 'business rules' and they should be decided by you or the party requesting this feature :-) Based on what properties of cells would make you consider two cells in two pictures are the same one, from your domain? If there are, can we get those properties from the pictures, or other data sources?